# Derivation of I_d of a self-biased JFET

Tags: dc, circuit-analysis, jfet, calculus

I find that derivations of formulas are a lot more useful to me than just recitations of formulas.  I'm looking at a self-biased JFET circuit, and I'm interested in deriving the quiescent state of the circuit under DC conditions.  Neglecting all AC components of the circuit, I have a very large resistor, \$R_g\$, between gate and ground, and another resistor, \$R_s\$, from source to ground.  Drain is connected to \$V_p\$, my power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiSYT8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I believe this is a fairly standard JFET circuit.  I understand how to analyze the circuit.  What I'm interested in is the derivation of \$I_{d}\$.  This is given to me as \$I_{d}=I_{dss} \left(1 - \frac{V_{gs}}{|V_p|)} \right) ^2\$.  None of the textbooks I've got on my shelf go into the derivation, nor did my google searches.  The closest I got was from a textbook that said that the JFET is a square-law component, and this relationship is intrinsic to the component.  I don't buy it.  Transconductance is intrinsic to the component.  Current flow isn't.  Can anyone show me how \$I_{d}\$ is derived?

Edit:  Sorry, I was asking for the wrong parameter and gave the wrong formula, as well.  Question is updated.

Edit:  Some discussion from Alfred Centauri pointed me in a good direction.  I've done a bit more work that I'll bring up here.  It's mostly turned into a math problem, now.

Essentially, I want to derive \$I_d\$ based on intrinsic properties of components.  Transconductance is a property of JFETs, so I started from there.

Knowing that \$g_m = \frac{dI_d(V_{gs})}{dV_{gs}}=\frac{2I_{dss}}{|V_p|} \left(1-\frac{V_{gs}}{|V_p|} \right)\$, I can rearrange and work some calculus, as follows.

$$
g_m = \frac{dI_d(V_{gs})}{dV_{gs}} \\
dI_d(V_{gs}) = g_mdV_{gs} \\
dI_d(V_{gs}) = \frac{2I_{dss}}{|V_p|} \left(1-\frac{V_{gs}}{|V_p|} \right) dV_{gs} \\
\int dI_d(V_{gs}) = \frac{2I_{dss}}{|V_p|} \int dV_{gs} - \frac{2I_{dss}}{|V_p|^2}\int V_{gs}dV_{gs} \\
I_d(V_{gs}) = \frac{2I_{dss}V_{gs}}{|V_p|} - \frac{I_{dss}V_{gs}^2}{|V_p|^2} + C
$$

We can find \$C\$ as we know \$I_d = I_{dss}\$ at \$V_{gs} = 0\$

$$
I_d(0) = \frac{2I_{dss}(0)}{|V_p|} - \frac{I_{dss}(0)^2}{|V_p|^2} + C \\
I_{dss} = C
$$

Therefore:

$$
I_d(V_{gs}) = \frac{2I_{dss}V_{gs}}{|V_p|} - \frac{I_{dss}V_{gs}^2}{|V_p|^2} + I_{dss} \\
I_d(V_{gs}) = I_{dss}\left(1 + \frac{2V_{gs}}{|V_p|} - \frac{V_{gs}^2}{|V_p|^2} \right) \\
$$

This is really close.  My target is \$I_{d}=I_{dss} \left(1 - \frac{V_{gs}}{|V_p|)} \right) ^2\$.  Think I can switch the signs of the terms by rolling the negative factor into my absolute value denominators?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  For a derivation of the JFET equation from physical principles, there are plenty of online resources.  Google:  "JFET device physics" and, for example, find [this](http://www-physics.lbl.gov/~spieler/physics_198_notes/PDF/VIII-4-FET.pdf).  The derivation is not trivial.

---

I'm not sure where you're getting your information but  \$I_{DSS}\$ isn't given by the equation you've written.  The following is from [Marshall Leach's JFET notes](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/ece3050/notes/jfet/thejfet.pdf):

In the saturation region of operation, the JFET total drain current is given by:

\$i_D = \beta (v_{GS} - V_{TO})^2\$ for \$v_{GS}> V_{TO} \$

Here, \$V_{TO}\$, the threshold or pinch-off voltage, is *negative*.

This can be written as:

\$i_D = I_{DSS}(1 - \dfrac{v_{GS}}{V_{TO}})^2\$

From the above, it is clear that \$i_D = I_{DSS} \$ when \$v_{GS} = 0 \$; it is the drain current when the gate and source have the same voltage.

[image]

Solving for \$I_{DSS} \$ gives:

\$I_{DSS} =  \beta V_{TO}^2\$

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake.  My fault for writing questions on here in the middle of class.  I'll update the question, since it's way wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  This is good.  It's helping me narrow down on what question I'm trying to ask.